# Choose one significant record from related table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I have a table with `customers`, and a table with `cities`.

In the customers table, the `city_id` is related to the `id_city` of the cities table.

Other fields in the tables

```
customers: name, surname
cities:    ext_code, description, address_code
```

The problem is that I have thousands of customers records related to cities in which the `ext_code` is not present.

The cities table, elsewhere, contains a lot of duplicated records; in the duplicated sets only one record has a valid `ext_code`.

The problem is: substitute the `city_id` with a `id_city` that contains a valid `ext_code`. The only fields to evaluate to group cities are `address_code` or `description`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have removed some of the accents as it was a little harder to read.  Please share your code so far.  It enabled others to help you faster.

Answer (score 0):

If the

> only fields to evaluate to group cities are address_code or
>   description

then that's what you should use to join your data on while filtering out the non "valid ext_code" that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crude way to do a one time update of customer.
You will need to tweak the code to make it work with your system, but that should be easy enough.

```
UPDATE    Customer
SET       CityID =
(
   --This bit will find cities that look like the one we already have, 
    SELECT TOP 1 CityID
    FROM         City AS X
    WHERE        X.AddressCode = City.AddressCode
    OR           X.Description = City.Description
    ORDER BY     X.ExtCode DESC --This puts nulls last!
)
FROM               Customer
INNER JOIN City ON City.CityID = Customer.CityID
```